# QTcpSocket do not load ssl

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sockets, networking

I'm writing my proxy server in Qt. It's already work, but sites with `https` don't work. Anybody know how to fix that? Maybe it's possible to replace `QTcpSocket` to `QSslSocket`? Or another way?

Comment: Of course QSslSocket.

Comment: @Greenflow just replace `QTcpSocket ` by `QSslSocket`?

Comment: Almost 'just'. Slightly different signals to connect, e.g. 'encrypted'. The documentation, which comes with Qt (QSslSocket) is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

try installing openssl as per docs:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example on Qt's forum. [You can find it here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/5009/simple-proxy-using-two-qtcpproxy/4) with source code in the comments. Also, make sure to include some code so we can further help you with your question.

Comment: This sample works like my project: I can't go to the site with `https`.